# My windows explorer shows future dates for date modified

Tags: windows-explorer

My windows explorer shows dates like tomorrow, next week and even later this year when grouping my files with date modified. What is going on?

Comment: perhaps this might help? http://www.ehow.com/how_8628825_check-futuredated-files-computer.html

Comment: No i want to fix the problem of the dates being wrong. They are completely messed up, for example in the group later this year I have a file that says its date modified is 06/12/2012 and this is in descending order but the files i have modified today are several groups further down.

Comment: Maybe it's not in the future. Maybe it's actually telling you that it was modified on 12/06/2012? What I mean is, American's have their days and months backwards (to Australia's). In Australia, it's Day/Month/Year. In the US it's Month/day/Year. Maybe your modified dates are just the wrong way around due to incorrect Time/Region settings?

Comment: Your computer is psychic. Sell it on eBay for $2 mil

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me there is one single possibility: these files came from a computer with a wrong time setting at the occasion of file transfer or that same computer had absurd sync problems with time servers.

Comment: Or maybe Matthew’s computer has the clock set incorrectly.

Comment: Indeed, but I assume he checked his settings for that matter before posting the question.

Comment: Yes, but read what he says: “… in the group **Later this year** I have a file that says its date modified is 06/12/2012 …” [formatting added]  If his computer thinks that 06/12/2012 is ***Later this year***, then this sounds like it is not a simple case of having acquired files with modification dates in the future.